# jquery ajax waiting end of php exec on other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following setup: a button when pressed is calling an ajax function which executes a php script from another page which will run a python script. First if you think there is a better way of doing this, I ready to hear it but this is the only way I managed to do this. My problem is I cannot get the ajax from jquery and php to talk to each other so that I can get feedback.

index.php has only a button calling a function with the id set to #btnpicture.

the ajax script is as follow:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).on('pageinit', '', function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#btnpicture', function() {
        $.ajax({url: 'actions.php',
                data: {action : 'takepicture'},
                type: 'post',                  
                async: 'true',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                    $.mobile.loading("show") // This will show ajax spinner
                },
                complete: function() {
                    // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                    $.mobile.loading("hide") // This will hide ajax spinner
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if(result.status) {
                        alert(status);                        
                    } else {
                        alert('Something went wrong taking the picture!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                }
            });                  
        });
```

I know there should be a closing }); but this script is rather long and I only show what is used here. It is working but it is just that I don't get what I want.

The page actions.php is:

```
<?php
require_once ("Config/Lite.php");

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case "takepicture": 
            $output = shell_exec("sudo rm /var/www/photo/*");
            exec("sudo python /home/pi/compteur/compteur.py -o /var/www/photo/photo -f", $output, $error);
            $status = end($output);
            $result = array('status' => $status);
            echo json_encode($result);
            break;
```

Here also, there are normally more lines but it is not written here.

So the script is working and the picture is being taken but the problem is that everything seems out of sync. The ajax script is not waiting for the exec command to have finished and send the result so that it can write it in the alert.

Thanks for your help if you have any idea on that.

Comment: it looks like you have a raspi and want to take a picture ... what does firebug or chrome google web developer tools (network tab in both) say about the ajax response?

Comment: what does the `-o` mean? Does it mean that `stdout` of the `compteur.py` is redirected to the `/var/www/photo/photo`

Comment: In fact, it goes to success before the camera finishes and I see in chrome that it says status object false for status. Then a while after, it says status = success. So it seems that it goes through the success function like 1 second after I press the button and it says it failed. Then when the camera has finished, the php script replies and then I see success. So when I press the button to take a picture, it goes 2 times through the success function.

Comment: -o is coming from my python script and this is to specify the output file of the photo. And -f is to specify it doesn't need to wait for the leds to light on.

Comment: can you share the request/response of the ajax calls from the developer tab?

Comment: where can I find that? Sorry, I m begining with ajax so I know how to use the debug in chrome (F12) but I don't know how to intercept what happens between the php and javascript files.

Comment: look here http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Ok, I looked at this and I an see a post being made to the actions.php page that finishes after 3 s and then another one also and it finishes after 30 seconds.

Comment: Of course the one that finishes after 3 seconds is not good because my python program is doing a lot of stuff and takes around 30 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78252/discussion-between-yuri-g-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you as documentation from the exec command:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> Note: If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

By passing -o to your python script, you are likely redirecting output to a file instead of standard out... Therefore, exec is seeing an immediate return and thinking the program is finished, or is running in the background...

Therefore, the php script is not waiting for your camera script to finish and is returning before the file can be output fully...

you could throw a wait loop in after the call to exec in php to check the file has completed outputting, or to watch that the pid no longer exists as output from the "ps" shell command.

Again, the problem is (likely) that the output is being redirected from stdout, and exec is returning thinking the process has been put in background run mode...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.

I have replaced and used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnpicture").click(function() {
```

instead and it is working fine now. I think my previous code was sending 2 requests each time I pressed the button.